# Error with JSON field using @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON) in Hibernate 6

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-envers

After upgrading to the latest Spring 3.1.1, the `@TypeDef` annotation is no longer available. It has been replaced with the `@JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON)` annotation. However, when persisting the entity, an error occurs while inserting into the `_aud` table:

Error Message:

`could not execute batch [Batch entry 0 insert into user_aud (revision_type,id,revision_id,payload) values (0,1,152,'{}') was aborted: ERROR: column "payload" is of type jsonb but expression is of type character varying Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.`

Code Snippet

```
@Audited
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
   @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    private String payload;
    ...
```

Comment: I guess that your `payLoad` should be of the same type as the actual object you store in the column, not `String`. But I am not sure with JPA, I use R2DBC normally so not much experience with JPA. In R2DBC I have to use `io.r2dbc.postgresql.codec.Json` if I want to be able to store any arbitrary type as JSON, and then I have to map my arbitrary object into it by `Json.of(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object))`. All the examples of `@JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON)` I found always use the *specific* type and not the JSON as string.

Comment: Also try running your code after upgrading to SB3 on a completely new database, just to eliminate different ways of JPA mappings. Anyway, https://www.google.com/search?q=ORM+is+an+offensive+antipattern and I loathe it :)

Comment: I see this as a workaround without envers @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON) does the conversion between json and String correctly and the record is persisted. I think envers does not respect @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON). It feels like this is missing feature.

Comment: @user1048282 any updates? I am facing the same issue except for a conversion from bytea to jsonb after upgrade to hibernate 6